# Calling functions with unknown number of arguments

Tags: function, go, variadic-functions, go-interface

I have the following `struct`:

```golang
// fninfo holds a function and its arity.
type fninfo struct {
    arity int // number of arguments that fn takes
    fn    any // fn must take string arguments and return one string
}
```

and a map of it:

```golang
var fnmap = map[string]fninfo{
    "not": fninfo{
        arity: 1,
        fn: func(a string) string // body omitted...
    },
    "add": fninfo{
        arity: 2,
        fn: func(a, b string) string // body omitted...
    },
    // more items...
}
```

What I want to do is, with any `fninfo`,
pop `fninfo.arity` number of `string`s from a stack (implementation omitted)
and call `fninfo.fn` with all the popped `string`s as arguments,
in a way similar to this:

```golang
info := fnmap[fnname]
args := make([]string, info.arity)
for i := 0; i < len(args); i++ {
    if args[i], err = stk.pop(); err != nil {
        // Handle error...
    }
}
info.fn(args...)
```

However, this is forbidden for two reasons:

1. `info.fn` cannot be directly called because
   it is of type `any` (`interface{}`)
2. `info.fn` cannot be called with a slice as its arguments
   because it is not a variadic function

Currently, all the functions I have take between 1-3 arguments,
so as a workaround,
I am manually popping each item and checking each type assertion:

```golang
info := fnmap[fnname]
if fn, ok := info.fn.(func(string) string); ok {
    a, err := stk.pop()
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error...
    }
    stk.push(fn(a))
} else if fn, ok := info.fn.(func(string, string) string); ok {
    a, err := stk.pop()
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error...
    }
    b, err := stk.pop()
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error...
    }
    stk.push(fn(a, b))
} else if fn, ok := info.fn.(func(string, string, string) string); ok {
    a, err := stk.pop()
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error...
    }
    b, err := stk.pop()
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error...
    }
    c, err := stk.pop()
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error...
    }
    stk.push(fn(a, b, c))
}
```

This is very long and repetitive,
and it becomes unmaintainable
should I add functions with 4, 5, or even more arguments.

How can I bypass the two problems I listed above
and have something similar to my second last example?
Is this possible to achieve in Go?
without reflection, and if not, with?

Comment: Use `func f(a ...string)`. Consult the spec.

Comment: And if you can't change the function signatures as suggested by Volker, your only other option, if you gotta stick with `fn any`, is to use reflection.

Comment: If you trust `arity` to match `fn`, then you don't need a type assertion, you can just use a type switch on `arity`. Although that raises the question: Why have both, since you can determine `arity` by looking at `fn`?

Comment: @JonathanHall how do can you determine `arity` by looking at `fn`?  Do you mean by reflection?

Comment: You have two options: reflection, or exactly what you're doing: A type assertion or type switch.

Comment: @ban_javascript if you want to avoid reflection, you can also just simplify your original design. For example you could do the following: https://go.dev/play/p/RlEDki2MG7R